# Unable to find "ServiceName" on Azure Free Trial

Tags: azure

I'm currently on an Azure free trial and trying to setup a reverse DNS PTR record.
I've logged in via certificate, downloaded the file using: `Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile`. I've also imported the file using `Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile C:certs<SubscriptionName>-credentials.publishsettings`.

However, when I run `Get-AzureService | fl ServiceName` I don't get any services listed.

When I try and run `Set-AzureService –ServiceName "my hostname" –Description "Reverse DNS" –ReverseDnsFqdn "mail.my domain."`

> I get The hosted Service name does not exist.

Is there a limitation on the free trial that doesn't allow this to be set?

Answer (score 0):

After Import... add

```
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "nameofyoursubscription"
```

Just importing your subscription publish settings file does not select the subscription you need.

UPD: i was not able to reproduce the issue. Please try to execute:

```
$subscr = "subscriptionid"
$csname = "mytestcloudservice14"
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscr –Current
New-AzureService -ServiceName $csname -Location "Central US" -Label "mytestcloudservice"
Set-AzureService –ServiceName $csname –Description "Reverse DNS" –ReverseDnsFqdn "mytestcloudservice14.cloudapp.net."
Get-AzureService -ServiceName $csname
```

I just created the trial account and tested it.[image]

Comment: Apologies, forgot to add that I did use that too. When I run that command, it just returns back to the command prompt.

Comment: Have also tried re-running "Get-AzureService | fl ServiceName" and that returns to the normal prompt too.

Comment: If I then run "Set-AzureService –ServiceName "my hostname" –Description "Reverse DNS" –ReverseDnsFqdn "mail.my domain." I still get the same error saying "The hosted Service name does not exist".

Comment: Yes, it should return you to the Azure Powershell command prompt without the output. May you try to use Add-AzureAccount instead of publish settings file and login using your admin credentials?

Comment: Thanks. Tried that but the Get_AzureService still doesn't return anything and just goes back to the prompt

Comment: ALso, when I rer-run the "Set-AzureService –ServiceName "my hostname" –Description "Reverse DNS" –ReverseDnsFqdn "mail.my domain." I still get the same error saying "The hosted Service name does not exist"

Comment: I will test it now with my free trial. There should be the issue, need to confirm.

Comment: Tried you command and when i get to "New-AzureService -ServiceName $csname -Location "Central US" -Label "mytestcloudservice" I get the following: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ServiceName'

Comment: @DFlack try to use the name itself instead of $csname, for example, "mytestcloudservice15"

Comment: What do you see when going to the http://manage.windowsazure.com to the Cloud Service section? Do you see the cloud service?

Comment: I'm managing my instance via https://portal.azure.com/ on the new virtual machine types. I see it in there along with my free subscription. The Cloud Services (classic) is empty.

Comment: Yes, if you create the VM using new portal (not classic VMs), there will be no cloud service because it is the classic model

Comment: So as I created mine in the new portal portal.azure.com under the new VM services, this doesn't support reverse DNS?

Answer (score 0):

As the description of `Get-AzureService` says, it returns an object with information about the cloud services for the current subscription, which means, it's an operation on **Azure cloud service** only, `Set-AzureService` as well.

So if you didn't deploy any cloud services, `Get-AzureService` will definitely list nothing and if your "my hostname" is not cloud service, it's no wonder you get the error message `The hosted service does not exist.`.

In addition, Reverse DNS is not supported for Azure Websites. Reverse DNS is supported for Azure PaaS roles and IaaS virtual machines.

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance but is a Windows VM not a cloud service?

Comment: No, only these under the left navigation **Cloud services** in the [classic portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com) are.

Comment: So as I created mine in the new portal https://portal.azure.com/ under the new VM services, this doesn't support reverse DNS?

Comment: To configure reverse DNS on VMs , you need to set the Reverse DNS property on the Public IP Address resource which can be implemented through Azure CLI cmdlet `azure network public-ip set -g <resource group> -n <public IP> -f <reverse fqdn>`

Comment: Configure via Powershell at https://www.samrobertson.co.uk/blog/2016/02/setting-reverse-dns-on-an-azure-vm-created-with-resource-manager/